# Django Rest Framework petición periodica bloquea servidor

Tags: django, apache, djangorestframework

Tengo un proyecto con Django 1.9, tengo una aplicación en Android que actualiza un campo en un modelo cada un segundo consumiendo la API Rest. El problema es que mientras este proceso sucede me cuelga el servidor, es decir no responde ante la misma petición desde otro cliente  y tampoco me deja ingresar al administrador de Django mediante SSH.

Comment: Debieras subir el detalle de las llamadas y funciones que estás invocando, por si hubiera algo mal programado que te tome toda la máquina.
¿estas usando el servidor de desarrollo o lo tienes ya en modo producción con apache/nginx?
Lo otro, podrias subir los detalles de tu hardware.

Comment: Lo tengo en modo produccion con Apache 2, medi el tiempo de respuesta de mi función y es mucho menor a un segundo (0.01 seg aprox). Lo tengo en un servidor web, donweb con centos 7  es un procesador de un nucleo de 3 Ghz 4Mb Cache 1Gb de Ram. No se si puede llegar a ser alguna confguración del Apache, pero tampoco se como poder medir eso.

Comment: Miraste en el archivo de log de errores de apache?
Las configuraciones de apache sí pueden influir.

Comment: Mire en el log, no me tira errores. La peticion se ejecuta correctamente, pero si detecte que no me deja llamar a otra api o a la misma desde otro cliente en simultaneo. Pero tambien detecte que las peticiones las atiende a veces cada segundo y a veces tarda aprox 5/6 segundos. Yo creo que por eso se cuelga, porque se apilan muchas solicitudes no atendidas

Comment: Como tienes configurado el apache en la parte de que use hilos o procesos?

Comment: Tengo las configuraciones por default  de la instalacion. No se que configuracion especifica me recomendas

Comment: Puedes subir la configuración de apache, para el modulo mod_wsgi (asumo que estás usando ese)?